# How to compute volume of polytope?

Tags: volume, polytopes, geometric-probability

I have a polytope $P$ described as the convex hull of finite points $u_1,..., u_m\in \mathbb R^n$. Is there an easy way to compute the volume of $P$ in $\mathbb R^n$?

So far I have it written as
$$
P = \{ Ux: 0\leq x\leq 1, x^T\mathbf 1 = 1\}
$$
where the columns of $U$ are $u_i$. 
I could conceivably get this into the form
$$
P = \{x : Ax \leq b\}
$$
for a clever choice of $A$ and $b$.

Any slick ways of computing the volume of $P$, using either $U$ or $A$ and $b$?

Comment: You can break it up into simplices, and use the determinant formula for the volume of a simplex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In reference to [this MathOverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/979/algorithm-for-finding-the-volume-of-a-convex-polytope), it looks like the answer is "there is no easy, general way to find such a volume."  If you need the volume of a specific polytope, the responses contain a link to [Qhull software](http://www.qhull.org/).  For more about computations of polytope computation see [Dr. Fukuda's FAQ](https://people.inf.ethz.ch/fukudak/Doc_pub/polyfaq220115c.pdf) and for more about the specifics of algorithms see [this study](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.42.7953&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the answer; it seems like if all the smart people are investigating numerical solutions, there most likely won't be closed form general solutions. Unfortunately I needed this for a theoretical, general result, but a negative answer is also pretty useful. thanks!